# new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application") missing window.document object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, activexobject

I have a weird problem with this code.  Basically I am loading a new ActiveXObject ("InternetExplorer.Application") and putting a reference to it onto the IE window object.  I then load up an HTML file and wait for it to finish loading before trying to run script against the new window.  When I launch IE via VS2010 with or without debugging (i.e. F5 or CTRL-F5) this code works and I get a reference to lDebugWindow.document.documentElement object.

The problem -- But when I just launch IE from the WIN7 taskbar, lDebugWindow.document is always undefined.  Any ideas what is different about IE when launched from VS2010 versus the taskbar?  Here is the code with the line highlighted that behaves differently from VS2010 vs. taskbar launch of IE:

```
function wfDebugXml(pNode)
{
    window.lDebugWindow = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
    lDebugWindow.navigate(sFrameworkBase + "/GlobalDebugger/Debug.htm");

    lReady = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if (!lReady)
        {
            try
            {
                lDebugWindow.onreadystatechange = wfDebugRenderXml(pNode);
            }
            catch (e) { };
        }
    }
}

function wfDebugRenderXml(pNode)
{
    // THE NEXT LINE IS THE ONE THAT HAS THE PROBLEM
    var lDocumentElement = lDebugWindow.document.documentElement;

    var lXsltDoc = Sarissa.getDomDocument();
    lXsltDoc.async = false;
    lXsltDoc.load("GlobalDebugger/Debug.xsl");

    var lXslt = new XSLTProcessor();
    lXslt.importStylesheet(lXsltDoc);

    var lXmlDoc = Sarissa.getDomDocument();
    lXmlDoc.loadXML(pNode.xml);

    var lXmlOutput = lXslt.transformToFragment(lXmlDoc, lDebugWindow.document);

    while (lDocumentElement.childNodes.length > 0)
    {
        lDocumentElement.removeChild(lDocumentElement.lastChild);
    }

    lDocumentElement.appendChild(lXmlOutput);
    lDebugWindow.Visible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is gone now. For anyone else, it might be a right access issue :
Under Win7 IE runs in a low integrity processus. I suppose it might not be possible to get COM pointers between processus with different levels of integrity.

I used ChangeWindowMessageFilter to fix my issue but I was communicating via messages. It might be a good point to start Googling though.